# DRF POST object with FK

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

First, my **models** :

```
class Director(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    director = models.ForeignKey(Director, related_name="movies")
```

I'd like to POST json files to create a director, a director with a movie (in once), or a movie.

So, here are my **serializers** :

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='movie')
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        exclude = ('director', )  # edit (solution) this line is the problem. It does not only affect the representation... Just remove that and it's OK


class DirectorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movies = MovieSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Director
        fields = '__all__'


    def create(self, validated_data):
        movies = validated_data.pop('movies')
        director = self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for movie in movies:
            Movie.objects.create(director=director, **movie)

        return director
```

So, (thanks httpie), to create a new director :

```
{
    "first_name": "Christopher",
    "last_name": "Nolan",
    "movies": []
}
```

works fine.
To create a new director with a movie :

```
{
    "first_name": "Luc",
    "last_name": "Besson",
    "movies": [
        {
            "title": "Le Grand Bleu"
        }
    ]
}
```

works too.
But I'm not able to **add a new movie** *i.e.* create a new movie.
JSON :

```
{
    "title": "Interstellar",
    "director": 1
}
```

director's id = 1 => C. Nolan ;-)

I think I'm missing something so if anyone could help me, advise me, or anything ?

Thanks, regards

#### EDIT the question is :

**What is the JSON file I have to POST to add "Interstellar" movie to Nolan's movies (id_director=1) ?**

Comment: What type of request and which endpoint are you using?

Comment: Have you used Django's Bulk create , if not please have a look at this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Comment: @zymud

**type of request ?? :** json datas via http using POST verb (that is what you wanted to know :/ ?). **Endpoint ??** Create a new *movie* in database.
*I'm not sure about your questions... sorry.*

Comment: @ChitrankDixit : I looked at querysets/bulk_create documentation. But I can't figure out how it could help me ?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not able to add a new movie here because you have excluded the `director` field in your MovieSerializer. But the director field is required by the Movie model. Removing the exclude should work

Comment: Damned ! I did that to represent *nicely* the REST directors list. Maybe you know how to do that, I mean, not repeat the director **id** in the director's list : `[ {"id": 1, "name": "C. Nolan", "movies": [{"title": "Interstellar", "director": 1}]}]` ? Thnak you very much.

Comment: Make the director field as `write_only` may be? But if you have a /movies/<movie> endpoint, you will not have the director data there. Else, you can override the to_representation of the MovieSerializer to remove the director details from the movie data

Comment: In fact, I think I want 2 differents representations of the *Movie* object. So 2 serializers...